# file, awk and iconv to automatically adapt tex-file encoding

Tags: awk, conversion, character-encoding

I have a set of tex-files with mixed encodings, e.g. (subset of output of `file -i *.tex`)

```
f1.tex: text/plain; charset=utf-8
f2.tex: text/plain; charset=utf-8
f3.tex: text/x-tex; charset=us-ascii
f4.tex: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
f5.tex: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
```

I want to convert them all to `utf-8`, especially those encoded `iso-8859-1`.
I can do this manually using (or similar)

```
iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 f4.tex > tmp && mv tmp f4.tex
```

but I thought this would be nicely possible using a combination of `awk` with the above, i.e. running `file -i` parsing this for file/encoding combinations using `awk` and performing the encoding conversion accordingly using `iconv`.

My knowledge of `awk` is rather limited. I got no further than this:

```
$ file -i *.tex | awk '{print $1, $3}'
f1.tex: charset=utf-8
f2.tex: charset=utf-8
f3.tex: charset=us-ascii
f4.tex: charset=iso-8859-1
f5.tex: charset=us-ascii
```

Any help appreciated! Especially, I don't know how I can strip the colon `:` and the `charset=` substrings off the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems it's much better to use sed here insted of awk:

```
file -i *tex | sed \ 
's/^\([^:]*\): .*set=\(.*\)/iconv -f \2 -t UTF-8 \1 > tmp \&\& mv tmp \1/e'
```

It would execute commands that `sed` will make based on `file -i` output.
If you want to look at commands list without executing just remove `e` flag at the end of sed script like this:

```
file -i *tex | sed \
's/^\([^:]*\): .*set=\(.*\)/iconv -f \2 -t UTF-8 \1 > tmp \&\& mv tmp \1/'
```

Comment: I'm intrigued by the `e` flag, but it probably is a GNU extension?  (That is, FreeBSD's `sed` doesn't know it.)

Comment: Yes, it is a GNU extension. I forgot to write about it. To use smth like that in non-GNU environment you can use contruction `echo "ehco Hello" | sed 's/hc/ch/' | bash` .